# Distributed mutex

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing

There are hundreds of servers in our cloud. There is a script which can be invoked at any time by any of these servers. I have to make sure that at any given time only one server is running the script. While one server has acquired lock on the script, and another server tries to execute, just write to a log file and exit. There can be multiple such scripts, each having a separate mutex lock. That means I want a solution which accommodates multiple servers multiple scripts. I am looking for a very simple solution. Please point to me to any available tool or suggest me on popular ways of implementing this.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want to implement something yourself like a single server which controls the locks for each script?

All your others servers would have to ask it for 'permission' to run the script and then inform it when they are done, probably with some timeout check mechanism also. You would need to think about having some high availability mechanism to ensue your 'lock controller' server does not become a single point of failure for the entire system. Also, you may want to check if you will need to queue requests rather than just existing - even if it is not a requirement now, if it is likely to become one it might be easier to design for it from the start.

Some common approaches are listed in the answers to these question here - the questions are a bit old but I think still relevant:

[Distributed Lock Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059580/distributed-lock-service)

[What are some good ways to do intermachine locking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448984/what-are-some-good-ways-to-do-intermachine-locking?lq=1)