# Python Threading, how to implement shared queue?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, task-queue

I'm using the Python module "Threading" to run a task in my code asynchronously and in a queued manner with `threadLock.release()` and  `threadLock.release()`.

The issue **IS** that i am running the same python program on like 4-5 computers and the asynchronous task that is being run makes changes to the same google sheet file and also some other files on dropbox etc, so if 2 or more of the computers are being used at the same time, it can cause issues because things get overwritten.

I love how things are running now locally on each computer, but I just need a way to get the `threadLock.release()` and `threadLock.release()` to communicate with the other computers running the same python program, basically a shared queue between computers. Is there possibly a simple fix in the threading module that i am missing?

Comment: Do the separate machines share anything? Filesystems, local network, credentials, ...?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, they share the same network (wifi), they're at the same workplace. Also they all have access to the same dropbox files.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448984/what-are-some-good-ways-to-do-intermachine-locking) help at all?