# How to achieve synchronization over multiple JVM's

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized, thread-synchronization

I have a piece of synchronized code which works effectively but I am facing issues while running multiple pods on K8s.
The scenario is that the DB update should happen only once at a time by that particular user which is mentioned in the native query and in the program.

Code block:

```
synchronized (this) {
    int calcAmount = person.getSum() + sal.getMonthlySal();
    calcAmount = calcAmount + refCount;
    int status = customQuery.updateUnit(calcAmount); 
}
```

There is some data manipulation which is programmatic and in the end the same needs to be updated in database.The person object needs to be handled in synchronous manner.

I do understand that there should be something which acquires the lock outside of JVM so that it can be monitored.
I am using Load Balancer in Round Robin pattern so requests will be served to all the JVM instances.

Can anyone please suggest what and how to save my thread operation so that doesn't breaks? ANy code snippet or link would be great to proceed with.

Comment: If you're querying a database from multiple clients then the synchronization should be done at the database level.

Comment: No, the code is only a part of all other operations being performed. I am fetching data and then performing some business logic followed by update in DB.

Comment: Perhaps you need a [distributed transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction).

Comment: This also seems related: [Synchronizing a Method Across JVM's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19389985/6395627).

Comment: Thanks @Slaw, but it looks like they are 3rd party libraries. I am trying to look for some solution from java. Doesn't java have any mechanism to handle DistributedLocking concepts?

Comment: In core Java? Probably not. In any case, I still think the synchronization should be done at the database level with an appropriate transaction.